# ActiveAdmin and custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to add an action_item to show page for back button

```
action_item :only => :show do
     link_to('Back', admin_feedbacks_path)
end
```

the back button was created in the last, here my question is how can i bring that button to first.(the customized action_item(back) was creat followed by the default actions_items like edit and delete)

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: my customized action_item was created at the last. i need that action_item into first.is there is any possibilities to change the options.

Comment: Do you want to change the position of the action item among the default resource action items?

Comment: yes i want to know how to change the position among with the default resource action items